# What would this postfix expression be in infix?

Tags: math, postfix-notation, infix-notation

First time here, anyone know what this postfix expression would be in infix?

`s s * x y z * * sqrt s t - / s t * +`

Where `sqrt` is square rooting.

My current guess is:
`(sqrt ((s * s) (x * y * z))) / (s - t) + (s * t)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's valid... You're one operator short

Comment: I count 9 inputs, so there needs to be 8 binary functions, but there's only 7 there.

Comment: But sqrt only takes one argument no?

Comment: Right. sqrt is a unary function. You need binary functions to turn two inputs into one value, so there needs to be one fewer binary functions than inputs in order to have one value at the end. Right now you end up with two values at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is one binary operator short, but for "how to convert", the details of what it is are irrelevant, so I'll assume it's `%`, which is unique in this equation and makes it easy to follow.

```
s s * x y z * * sqrt s t - / s t * + %
```

The first step is to find each operator, and put a `)` after it, and then count back however many values that operator takes (usually 2) and put a `(` before it. This gives us a fully parenthesized equation

```
((s s *) ((((x (y z *) *) sqrt) (s t -) /) (s t *) +) %)
```

Then we move the operators one value to the left (usually from the "post" position, to the "in" position)

```
((s * s) % (((sqrt (x * (y * z))) / (s - t)) + (s * t)))
```

This gives us a valid infix equation. Then we remove any redundant parenthesis from this. (I left both sides of the `%` parenthesized, since I don't know what operator it was supposed to be)

```
(s * s) % (sqrt(x * y * z) / (s - t) + s * t)
```